# How to ignore errors that Pylint picks up from method stubs?

Tags: vim, pylint, syntastic, vim-syntastic

I'm coding in Vim, using Syntastic and Pylint. Sometimes I like to put in method stubs like so:

```
def foo(bar, baz):
    pass
```

I know that I am going to use `bar` and `baz` and I'd rather Pylint not tell me that I ignored some parameters if I ignored them intentionally with a `pass` statement. Is there anyway to silence this error specifically in this case only? I still want it to warn me about unused variables on functions I've implemented in full.

Comment: You can disable (and later re-enable) `unused-argument` with [magic comments](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/message-control.html).  All Pylint, nothing to do with syntastic.

Comment: IIRC, rather `raise NotImplementedError()` than `pass` and pylint will consider the method as an abstract method, which is not expected to consume its arguments.